# An example of a statement easily provable in set theory but not in Peano arithmetic

Tags: logic, soft-question, infinity

I have 3 examples but each of them has its own flaws. They are *consistency of Peano arithmetics*, [Goodstein's Theroem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein's_theorem) and [*-Ramsey's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem). I would love something what can be explained together with its proof in set theory in, say, 20 minutes to a person interested math but not knowing the mathematical logics or set theory -- something what would elegantly demonstrate the power the infinity.

What I dislike on mentioned examples:

1. *Consistency of Peano arithmetics*: I think that this one is the worst one because it is pretty difficult to even state. And the proof by construction of a model feels a bit like a cheat.
2. *Goodstein's Theorem*: If we state it by cutting hydra, it can be easily confused with something provable in PA but the base-$n$ definition is nice. A bigger problem is that the proof requires ordinal numbers. They are quite difficult to explain and if I introduced them really briefly, the listener wouldn't feel very convinced.
3. *Paris–Harrington theorem*: I really like the proof of infinite Ramsey theorem. If it ended there, I would be satisfied. Unfortunately then the technical compactness principle is required. And those things which are trivial but technical are the most difficult to explain.

So, I am interested whether the property "Being provable in ZFC but not in PA" can be distilled (perhaps from 2. and 3.) to something with a proof simple enough.

Comment: hi Mirek, seems you're had to get in touch with. I was interested in getting in touch with u because of ur NIPS submission. Feel free to ping me at miranda9@illinois.edu